# Highcharts.pathToArray is not a function

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have recently upgrade highcharts in my project from `v4.0.4` to `v8.2.0` the latest.

In my code I am using this map: http://www.highcharts.com/studies/world-map.htm

I populate the data like so:

```
for (var i = 1; i < countryCodes.length; i++) {     
if (shapes[countryCodes[i]]) {
    options.series[0].data.push({
        y : parseFloat(populationDensities[i]),
        name : countryNames[i],
        path : Highcharts.pathToArray(shapes[countryCodes[i]]),
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#FF7F00' // orange
            }
        }

    });
}
```

However after the upgrade I get the `Highcharts.pathToArray is not a function`

I cannot seem to find the equivalent of this on the new version.

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor which I could work on? Without seeing your options it's hard to say what could have an impact for this error occurring.

Comment: The issues is on updating highcharts on a .net project.. Would not be able to reproduce it like that

Comment: Lulutho Mgwali, do you use the official Highcharts .NET wrapper? https://dotnet.highcharts.com/

Comment: Only to build viewmodels but otherwise the Javascript package

Comment: So why can't you reproduce your issue with the sample/hardcoded data? You can start from this template: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/data-class-ranges

Comment: Looking at this, the major difference is the implementation of the chart, the above fiddle uses the `Highcharts.mapChart` call to initiate the chart implementation. I might have to do a rewrite. I was trying to avoid that. Thanks.